# Threads, concurrent futures, or Asyncio

Tags: multithreading, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

Good Day,

I have an application that I am trying to code but I need to better understand the best way to handle solving the problem

Problem:  A webcam stream that is monitoring a street (running east-west).  I have two masks ROIs.  I want to detect when a car passes through one ROI to start a timer then I want to stop the timer when it passes through the second mask ROI.    I want to also assess whether the car is traveling east or west.[image]

I am grateful for any help you can provide to get me on the best approach  [image]

I found this example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWt5lpn8fN8  which I think might work using async while, except, and finally approach.  Once I have created the ROIs in Main the async def could be used to sample whether the ROI max is > 50 hence triggering a timer.   Having never used async before I am not sure of the architecture/syntax of the code.   I hope I am making sense....

Here is my synchronous code.  Its pretty standard for creating ROIs

```
L_mask_E = cv2.imread('left_mask_East.png',0)
R_mask_E = cv2.imread('far_right_mask_East-1.png',0)
    
   
L_mask_E_sized=cv2.resize(L_mask_E,frameDelta.shape[1::-1])
R_mask_E_sized=cv2.resize(R_mask_E,frameDelta.shape[1::-1])
    

    

 L_mask_E_roi = cv2.bitwise_and(frameDelta,L_mask_E_sized)
 L_smallest_E = L_mask_E_roi.min(axis=(0,1))

 L_largest_E=L_mask_E_roi.max(axis=(0, 1))

 R_mask_E_roi = cv2.bitwise_and(frameDelta,R_mask_E_sized)
 R_smallest_E=R_mask_E_roi.min(axis=(0,1))
    
 R_largest_E = R_mask_E_roi.max(axis=(0, 1))

 L_end=0
 R_end=0

 L_time.append(abs(time.time()-L_start))
 R_time.append(R_start-time.time())
   
    
 L_Largest_E_list.append(L_largest_E)
 R_Largest_E_list.append(R_largest_E)
  

 if L_Largest_E_list[len(L_Largest_E_list)-1]>100:
        L_time_peak=[]

        if abs(L_time[-1]-L_time[-2])<.15:
            print('abs(L_time[-1]-L_time[-2]=',abs(L_time[-1]-L_time[-2]))
            Lpeak.append(L_Largest_E_list)
            
            L_time_peak.append(L_time[-1])
            print('L_time_peak=',L_time_peak[-1])
            print('L_time=',L_time[-1])
            #print('Lpeak=',Lpeak)
            #print('L_time_peak=',L_time_peak)

            avg_Lpeaks.append(statistics.mean(Lpeak[-1]))
        
            L_time_peaks.append(L_time[-1])
            avg_L_time_peak.append(statistics.mean(L_time_peak))
            print('avg_L_time_peak=',avg_L_time_peak)
            L_time_peak=[]
            Lpeak=[]
```

[image]

As you can see have successfully implemented a threshold to isolate the impulse caused by passing cars.  Unfortunately, I am getting about six points appended to the list every time.  I really want to average these points.